# Vulkan descriptor set best practice

Tags: c++11, 3d, rendering, vulkan

I use vulkan to render 3D scene and I want to write a "not too badly" optimized scene manager, i try to figure out the best way of using descriptor set but i'm not sure.

Let's say I have a scene with 100 objects:

Should i have 100 differents descriptor sets, each bound to differents buffers containing the transformation matrix of an object in the scene.

OR

Should i have only one descriptor set and update the descriptor set between each draw command call in order to bound the buffer to the next object's transformation matrix ??

This question is also relevant about textures.